# Regex to find string within line range in Eclipse search

Tags: regex, eclipse

I'm trying to create a regex that will search for text within a range.

Let say I'd want to start from the third column index and search for the word `hit` from that point and 20 columns beyond that.

So far I have [this](https://regex101.com/r/lV5Dpw/1):

```
(?<=.{3})(\bhit\b)


  hit hit hit hithit hit hit hit
```

So with that line, I'd like to match the second and third hit. The fourth hit should not match because it'd fall in the 21-24 range.

Comment: So, what is the question? Does your regex work as expected?

Comment: It partially works, but I'm having trouble finding out how to set the "end" point or a range.

Comment: In which language you want to use it?

Comment: Add the corresponding language tag

Comment: @ManzoorWani I'm using it in Eclipse in the Find/Replace dialog. I'm not sure what language that would be under.

Comment: You may use `(?<=.{3})(\bhit\b).{20}` to match 20 characters after `hit` and then use the 1st capturing group to get what you want

Comment: @ManzoorWani I believe I understand what you suggested. But I'm trying to get individual matches for each `hit`. So in the link, if the range is 3 - 23, it'll match the second and third `hit` and not the fourth one because the entire word will not be in that range.

Comment: How about simply something like `^....{0,17}\bhit\b`. [See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SHdqNo/1).

Comment: @RegexNoob, You should provide a few examples of the text that you want to match and that you want to avoid

Comment: @ClasG I'd like to capture/ match each `hit` within the range. I appreciate your suggestion though.

Comment: @ManzoorWani I edited it to hopefully show what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What you are trying to do may not be possible in a Find/Replace dialog. You should try to use some program/script and process the desired text using Regex.